# Not replace hex code in jquery preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a basic system to replace some characters.

Example:

\t - Replace for tab-size 4
\n - Replace for

this working very good, but, when is replaced a hex code (In this case the format is: {FFFFFF}) not work if the code is on pos 1 or more. Only work if the code is in first pos of string of the textarea

[image]

code =

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#dialog_edit_input').keyup(function()
    {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var start = -1, end = -1;
        // Backspaces (\t, \n)
        val = val.replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
        val = val.replace(/\\t/g, "<p class=\"create_t\"></p>");

        // Extraer colores hex PAWN
        start = val.search("{");
        end = val.indexOf("}", (start != -1 ? start+6 : 0));

        var is_posible = ((start != -1  && end != -1) && end == start + 7);
        var _color_real = is_posible ? val.substr(start, end+1) : null;
        var _color = _color_real != null ? _color_real.substr(1, _color_real.length-2) : null;

        if(is_posible)
            val = val.replace(_color_real, "<span style=\"color: #" + _color + "\">");

        console.log(end);
        $('#agregar_resultado').html(val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression like you did for the other substitutions:

```
val = val.replace(/\{([0-9A-Fa-f]{6})\}/g, '<span style="color: #$1">');
```

Notes:

1. The parentheses in the regular expression create a group. That means the six hex digits will form the first (and only) group. Notice that the braces are not within the parentheses. They are necessary for a match to take place, but they are not part of the group.
2. The `$1` in the substitution string will be replaced with the value of the first matched group, which in this case is the six hex digits.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0eedc5ub/4/)

---

As for why your code is not working as written, you are looking for only one occurrence. Instead, you would need to have a loop.

```
    var pos = 0;
    while (pos < val.length) {
        var start = val.indexOf('{', pos);
        if ((start >= 0) && ((start + 7) < val.length)) {
            if (val.charAt(start + 7) == '}') {
                var color = val.slice(start + 1, start + 7);
                var replacement = '<span style="color: #' + color + '">';
                val = val.slice(0, start) + replacement + val.slice(start + 8);
                pos = start + replacement.length;
            } else {
                pos = start + 1;
            }
        } else {
            pos = val.length;
        }
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0eedc5ub/2/)